# application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is not printing anything inside it

Tags: swift

I am in the process of testing push notifications on a bare bones app. Currently, all it does is receive push notifications and do nothing else.

When I try to `print()` out info inside the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function it refuses to print anything.

My code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        print("TEST TEST TEST")
        registerForPushNotifications(application)
        print("TEST TEST TEST")
        if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print(notification)
            let aps = notification["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            print(aps)
        }
        return true
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
}
```

None of the print lines in the function print anything to the console. I have confirmed they are being hit by using breakpoints. Why are is nothing being printed?

I was able to find a workaround with using alerts, and those work great and give me all the info I need, but it doesn't help answer why nothing is being printed in the console.

Workaround Code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        UIAlertView(title: "Remote Notif", message: "\(launchOptions)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
        registerForPushNotifications(application)
        if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            UIAlertView(title: "Remote Notif", message: "\(notification)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
            let aps = notification["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
            UIAlertView(title: "Remote Notif", message: "\(aps)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
        }
        return true
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
}
```

I am aware that UIAlertView is deprecated, but it still works fine for now.

Some extra info:
It is being run on a device.
The Run Scheme is set up so it waits for an executable to be launched (a user pressing on a push notification for instance).
The Main Storyboard file base name in my .plist is "Main"

---

After further testing, it seems like it only happens when my Launch Scheme is set to `Wait for executable to be launched`, if it is set to `Automatically` launch, it will print out the lines.  The only thing I can think of is maybe the console isn't being booted up when woken up from a push notification. So it might be a bug with Xcode.

Comment: Are you running this on a device or just in the simulator?

Comment: Running on a device.

Comment: 2 things to test - move your print statement above your call to registerForPushNotifications and see if it prints anything, and also check your .plist and let me know what it says under "Main storyboard file base name"

Comment: Also consider, just as a test, throwing your let notification settings = UIUser...into an "if let" statement. Immediately after the first opening bracket, throw in a print statement, and see if it prints anything out.

Comment: Nothing is being printed in the Xcode console or on the device console? If you're printing to the device console you have to use NSLog()

Comment: @karansatia Alright, I put another print statement above the registerForPushNotifications, no change. I attempted to put the notification settings into an `if let`, but it gives me an error saying `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIUserNotificationSettings'` Also I updated the question with you question on what the Main Storyboard file base name is.

Comment: @Amloelxer Xcode console, I had no idea there was a device console.

Comment: @TaylorAllred in your target scheme is your build configuration on Run set to Debug? Also can you try replacing your print statements with NSLog and see what happens?

Comment: @Amloelxer Yes, it is.

Comment: can you check if UIUserNotificationSettings is an optional type? Your error message regarding optionals is saying "you don't need this statement unless you're checking for a value that could be nil". If the right expression in the "if let" statement isn't an optional type, then it can't be nil and an "if let" check is unnecessary.

Comment: UIUserNotificationSettings is not an optional type.

Comment: Forget the "if let", then. Try putting a print statement inside of the app delegate's application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method. You can use that method to determine if your request was granted or denied by the user. It's probably not in there so just type it into Xcode and let it autocomplete. Build the program, accept notifications on your device, and make sure that delegate method is getting hit by using your print statement.

Comment: @TaylorAllred Did you try NSLog instead of print and see if that does anything?

Comment: NSLog also doesn't print anything.

Comment: @TaylorAllred try using the delegate method. That's what it's there for.

Comment: I updated the question with some more testing, looks like it might be an Xcode bug.

Comment: @TaylorAllred Glad you found your answer - definitely a tricky problem to solve. Without testing using print statements and delegate methods, it would've been hard to pinpoint Xcode settings as being the problem :) It'd be interesting to dig deeper and figure out why UIAlerts would work while the launch was waiting for the executable but print statements wouldn't. Let us know if you find anything on the subject!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that having `Wait for application to be launched` causes the Xcode debug console not to start with the application. I don't know if this intended or an Xcode bug. Try selecting `Launch automatically` in your scheme and your debug console should turn back on. You also may need to restart xCode after changing the scheme.